# LinqToExcel C# - How to NOT read empty row

Tags: c#, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

I want to read data from an excel table that looks like this:
[image: Excel Table Screenshot]

Worksheet name is `"Data"`. I store the data into `List<ExcelData>`. Then I do a `List.Count`, and **it is more than 11 even though I only have 11 non-empty rows.**

```
    public class ExcelData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FgCmd { get; set; }
        public string SwCmd { get; set; }
    }

    public void PrintExcelTable()
    {
        var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"C:\sample.xlsx");

        var tableData = from z in excelFile.Worksheet<ExcelData>("Data")
                        select z;

        var List = tableData.ToList<ExcelData>();

        Console.WriteLine(List.Count);
    }
```

I want my `List` to store only the non-empty row. Any workaround? *Preferably be solved during the LinQ selection, not by removing empty data from List after.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a where clause :

```
from z in excelFile.Worksheet<ExcelData>("Data") where z.id != ""
                        select z;
```

Comment: Tried that, I would get weird error saying `'Data' is not a valid worksheet name`. But `Data` is exactly my worksheet name!

Comment: I think it is something about the unary and member expression.

Comment: What if you try putting ToList<ExcelData>() here : z in excelFile.Worksheet<ExcelData>("Data").ToList<ExcelData>() where...

Comment: Actually, the problem lies in excel, not the code. I'm so sorry. I'm not sure why, but after I deleted all the empty rows under the table, the code now works as intended.

Comment: Anyway, if user accidentally put down a empty space in `Id` column, `z.Id != ""` is not able to handle that. Can you suggest a better `.Where` condition?

Comment: I think `where (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(z.Id))` solves that. Let me know if you have better suggestion.